# Adding own controller to RespondCMS

Tags: respondcms

I am trying to add my own controller to my RespondCMS site. I inserted my code into respond.controllers.js

```
(function () {
 angular.module('respond.controllers')
.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
 $scope.item="Hello World";
})

}();
```

and tried to access it on  a page with HTML5 code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 Print {{item}}
 </div>
```

But it does not work.

Any ideas how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are supposed to directly edit /js/respond.controllers.js.

I think what you need to do is edit the files under /js/controllers, and then cd to the root project folder and type "gulp" to concatenate everything into a single respond.controllers.js file.

You will need to install gulp and a few other gulp modules, which in turn requires the installation of node and npm.